# Can you help me parse this XML w/ PHP?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm trying to write a payment and Xero integration for our PSA software. The billing part has gone pretty well thanks to help around here. Now the fun part comes: Parsing the Invoice Data from the API of the PSA to usable data that I can feed into Xero...

Here is the XML as it comes from the API:

```
<invoice_batch_generic xmlns="http://tempuri.org/invoice_batch_generic.xsd">
    <invoice_batch>
        <batch_id>171</batch_id>
        <create_date>2017-07-11T14:23:39.133-04:00</create_date>
        <create_by_id>29682885</create_by_id>
        <batch_data />
    </invoice_batch>
    <taxregioncategory>
        <tax_category_name />
        <total_tax_rate_per_category_and_region>0.0000000</total_tax_rate_per_category_and_region>
        <total_tax_amount>0.00000</total_tax_amount>
    </taxregioncategory>
    <account>
        <account_id>232</account_id>
        <parent_name />
        <creator_name>Dominic</creator_name>
        <narrative_creator_name>Dominic</narrative_creator_name>
        <territory_name />
        <cust_id />
        <cust_name>Metro </cust_name>
        <taxable>No</taxable>
        <addr1>123 Anywhere Ln</addr1>
        <addr2 />
        <city>Denver</city>
        <account_region>CO</account_region>
        <country>United States</country>
        <postal_code>80203</postal_code>
        <phone>1234567890</phone>
        <fax />
        <attention />
        <billing_addr1>132 anywhere ln</billing_addr1>
        <billing_addr2 />
        <billing_city>Denver</billing_city>
        <billing_region>CO</billing_region>
        <billing_country>United States</billing_country>
        <billing_postal_code>80203</billing_postal_code>
        <billing_attention />
        <tax_id />
        <tax_group_name />
        <parent_id />
        <payment_term_name>NET 15</payment_term_name>
        <account_invoice_email_recipient></account_invoice_email_recipient>
        <invoice>
            <invoice_id>471</invoice_id>
            <account_id>232</account_id>
            <owner_name>Dominic</owner_name>
            <narrative_owner_name>Dominic</narrative_owner_name>
            <invoice_date>2017-07-11T00:00:00-04:00</invoice_date>
            <entry_time_stamp>2017-07-11T14:23:39-04:00</entry_time_stamp>
            <invoice_number>2374</invoice_number>
            <comments />
            <invoice_total>1087.0800</invoice_total>
            <total_tax_value>0.0000</total_tax_value>
            <tax_description />
            <tax_group />
            <date_range_from>2017-08-01T00:00:00-04:00</date_range_from>
            <date_range_to>2017-08-30T00:00:00-04:00</date_range_to>
            <purchase_order_number />
            <payment_term_name>NET 15</payment_term_name>
            <batch_id>171</batch_id>
            <invoice_transferred_flag>No</invoice_transferred_flag>
            <payment_due_date>2017-07-26T00:00:00-04:00</payment_due_date>
            <taxes />
            <invoice_item>
                <invoice_item_id>1</invoice_item_id>
                <invoice_id>471</invoice_id>
                <item_name>SOME STUFF</item_name>
                <item_id>9234</item_id>
                <item_date>2017-08-01T00:00:00-04:00</item_date>
                <adjusted_item_id />
                <type_of_transaction>Recurring Service</type_of_transaction>
                <allocation_code_name>Managed Services</allocation_code_name>
                <allocation_code_external_number />
                <allocation_code_non_billable>No</allocation_code_non_billable>
                <allocation_code_taxable>No</allocation_code_taxable>
                <task_or_ticket_number />
                <task_or_ticket_title>Recurring Service</task_or_ticket_title>
                <ticket_contact />
                <narrative_ticket_contact />
                <adjustment_reason />
                <resource_name> Dominic</resource_name>
                <narrative_resource_name>Dominic </narrative_resource_name>
                <resource_payroll_identifier />
                <role_name />
                <department>Operations</department>
                <project_name />
                <project_lead />
                <narrative_project_lead />
                <external_project_number />
                <internal_project_number />
                <gl_code_desc />
                <gl_code_name />
                <contract_name>Metro 2017</contract_name>
                <external_contract_number />
                <worked_hours>0.0000</worked_hours>
                <non_billable_hours>0.0000</non_billable_hours>
                <billable_hours>0.0000</billable_hours>
                <hourly_billing_rate>21.4800</hourly_billing_rate>
                <extended_price>859.2000</extended_price>
                <time_entry_summary_notes />
                <quantity>40.0000</quantity>
                <expense_type />
                <installed_product_name />
                <subscription_name />
                <subscription_desc />
                <subscription_cost>0.00</subscription_cost>
                <milestone_title />
                <milestone_description />
                <milestone_amount>0.0000</milestone_amount>
                <service_or_bundle_id>63</service_or_bundle_id>
                <service_name>STUFF</service_name>
                <service_invoice_description>STUFF</service_invoice_description>
                <service_units>40</service_units>
                <service_unit_price>21.4800</service_unit_price>
                <service_extended_price>859.2000</service_extended_price>
                <service_period_start_date>2017-08-01T00:00:00-04:00</service_period_start_date>
                <service_period_end_date>2017-08-31T00:00:00-04:00</service_period_end_date>
                <setup_fee>0.0000</setup_fee>
                <billing_approved_by>, Dominic</billing_approved_by>
                <narrative_billing_approved_by>Dominic </narrative_billing_approved_by>
                <approved_date>2017-07-11T11:03:25.957-04:00</approved_date>
                <posted_date>2017-07-10T20:00:00-04:00</posted_date>
                <non_overage_retainer_line_item_tax>0.0000</non_overage_retainer_line_item_tax>
                <gross_amount>859.2000</gross_amount>
                <contract_type>7</contract_type>
                <department_number />
                <effective_hourly_billing_rate>21.4800</effective_hourly_billing_rate>
                <external_product_id />
                <cost_description />
                <project_phase />
                <our_cost>310.0000</our_cost>
                <expense_description />
                <line_item_id>1</line_item_id>
                <tax_region_and_category_id>0</tax_region_and_category_id>
                <tax_region_name />
                <tax_category_name />
                <total_tax_rate_per_region_and_category>0.0000000</total_tax_rate_per_region_and_category>
                <total_tax_amount>0.00000</total_tax_amount>
                <allocation_code_id>29682901</allocation_code_id>
                <serial_number />
                <contract_period_type>m</contract_period_type>
                <service_period_type>m</service_period_type>
                <account_manager_when_posted>, Dominic</account_manager_when_posted>
            </invoice_item>
            <invoice_item>
                <invoice_item_id>2</invoice_item_id>
                <invoice_id>471</invoice_id>
                <item_name>SEServer [Aug 01, 2017 - Aug 31, 2017]</item_name>
                <item_id>9235</item_id>
                <item_date>2017-08-01T00:00:00-04:00</item_date>
                <adjusted_item_id />
                <type_of_transaction>Recurring Service</type_of_transaction>
                <allocation_code_name>Managed Services</allocation_code_name>
                <allocation_code_external_number />
                <allocation_code_non_billable>No</allocation_code_non_billable>
                <allocation_code_taxable>No</allocation_code_taxable>
                <task_or_ticket_number />
                <task_or_ticket_title>Recurring Service</task_or_ticket_title>
                <ticket_contact />
                <narrative_ticket_contact />
                <adjustment_reason />
                <resource_name>, Dominic</resource_name>
                <narrative_resource_name>Dominic </narrative_resource_name>
                <resource_payroll_identifier />
                <role_name />
                <department>Operations</department>
                <project_name />
                <project_lead />
                <narrative_project_lead />
                <external_project_number />
                <internal_project_number />
                <gl_code_desc />
                <gl_code_name />
                <contract_name>Metro  2017</contract_name>
                <external_contract_number />
                <worked_hours>0.0000</worked_hours>
                <non_billable_hours>0.0000</non_billable_hours>
                <billable_hours>0.0000</billable_hours>
                <hourly_billing_rate>110.4800</hourly_billing_rate>
                <extended_price>220.9600</extended_price>
                <time_entry_summary_notes />
                <quantity>2.0000</quantity>
                <expense_type />
                <installed_product_name />
                <subscription_name />
                <subscription_desc />
                <subscription_cost>0.00</subscription_cost>
                <milestone_title />
                <milestone_description />
                <milestone_amount>0.0000</milestone_amount>
                <service_or_bundle_id>62</service_or_bundle_id>
                <service_name>SECURE MANAGED SERVICES: Server</service_name>
                <service_invoice_description>Secure Managed Services Per Server</service_invoice_description>
                <service_units>2</service_units>
                <service_unit_price>110.4800</service_unit_price>
                <service_extended_price>220.9600</service_extended_price>
                <service_period_start_date>2017-08-01T00:00:00-04:00</service_period_start_date>
                <service_period_end_date>2017-08-31T00:00:00-04:00</service_period_end_date>
                <setup_fee>0.0000</setup_fee>
                <billing_approved_by>, Dominic</billing_approved_by>
                <narrative_billing_approved_by> Kirby</narrative_billing_approved_by>
                <approved_date>2017-07-11T11:03:25.957-04:00</approved_date>
                <posted_date>2017-07-10T20:00:00-04:00</posted_date>
                <non_overage_retainer_line_item_tax>0.0000</non_overage_retainer_line_item_tax>
                <gross_amount>220.9600</gross_amount>
                <contract_type>7</contract_type>
                <department_number />
                <effective_hourly_billing_rate>110.4800</effective_hourly_billing_rate>
                <external_product_id />
                <cost_description />
                <project_phase />
                <our_cost>91.5000</our_cost>
                <expense_description />
                <line_item_id>2</line_item_id>
                <tax_region_and_category_id>0</tax_region_and_category_id>
                <tax_region_name />
                <tax_category_name />
                <total_tax_rate_per_region_and_category>0.0000000</total_tax_rate_per_region_and_category>
                <total_tax_amount>0.00000</total_tax_amount>
                <allocation_code_id>29682901</allocation_code_id>
                <serial_number />
                <contract_period_type>m</contract_period_type>
                <service_period_type>m</service_period_type>
                <account_manager_when_posted>, Dominic</account_manager_when_posted>
            </invoice_item>
            <invoice_item>
                <invoice_item_id>3</invoice_item_id>
                <invoice_id>471</invoice_id>
                <item_name>SECURE MANAGED SERVICES: Firewall  [Aug 01, 2017 - Aug 31, 2017]</item_name>
                <item_id>9236</item_id>
                <item_date>2017-08-01T00:00:00-04:00</item_date>
                <adjusted_item_id />
                <type_of_transaction>Recurring Service</type_of_transaction>
                <allocation_code_name>Hardware as a Service</allocation_code_name>
                <allocation_code_external_number>HWAAS</allocation_code_external_number>
                <allocation_code_non_billable>No</allocation_code_non_billable>
                <allocation_code_taxable>No</allocation_code_taxable>
                <task_or_ticket_number />
                <task_or_ticket_title>Recurring Service</task_or_ticket_title>
                <ticket_contact />
                <narrative_ticket_contact />
                <adjustment_reason />
                <resource_name>, Dominic</resource_name>
                <narrative_resource_name>Dominic </narrative_resource_name>
                <resource_payroll_identifier />
                <role_name />
                <department>Operations</department>
                <project_name />
                <project_lead />
                <narrative_project_lead />
                <external_project_number />
                <internal_project_number />
                <gl_code_desc />
                <gl_code_name />
                <contract_name>Metro  2017</contract_name>
                <external_contract_number />
                <worked_hours>0.0000</worked_hours>
                <non_billable_hours>0.0000</non_billable_hours>
                <billable_hours>0.0000</billable_hours>
                <hourly_billing_rate>6.9200</hourly_billing_rate>
                <extended_price>6.9200</extended_price>
                <time_entry_summary_notes />
                <quantity>1.0000</quantity>
                <expense_type />
                <installed_product_name />
                <subscription_name />
                <subscription_desc />
                <subscription_cost>0.00</subscription_cost>
                <milestone_title />
                <milestone_description />
                <milestone_amount>0.0000</milestone_amount>
                <service_or_bundle_id>64</service_or_bundle_id>
                <service_name>SECURE MANAGED SERVICES: Firewall TZ300</service_name>
                <service_invoice_description>SonicWALL TZ300 Managed Firewall</service_invoice_description>
                <service_units>1</service_units>
                <service_unit_price>6.9200</service_unit_price>
                <service_extended_price>6.9200</service_extended_price>
                <service_period_start_date>2017-08-01T00:00:00-04:00</service_period_start_date>
                <service_period_end_date>2017-08-31T00:00:00-04:00</service_period_end_date>
                <setup_fee>0.0000</setup_fee>
                <billing_approved_by>, Dominic</billing_approved_by>
                <narrative_billing_approved_by>Dominic </narrative_billing_approved_by>
                <approved_date>2017-07-11T11:03:25.957-04:00</approved_date>
                <posted_date>2017-07-10T20:00:00-04:00</posted_date>
                <non_overage_retainer_line_item_tax>0.0000</non_overage_retainer_line_item_tax>
                <gross_amount>6.9200</gross_amount>
                <contract_type>7</contract_type>
                <department_number />
                <effective_hourly_billing_rate>6.9200</effective_hourly_billing_rate>
                <external_product_id />
                <cost_description />
                <project_phase />
                <our_cost>46.0000</our_cost>
                <expense_description />
                <line_item_id>3</line_item_id>
                <tax_region_and_category_id>0</tax_region_and_category_id>
                <tax_region_name />
                <tax_category_name />
                <total_tax_rate_per_region_and_category>0.0000000</total_tax_rate_per_region_and_category>
                <total_tax_amount>0.00000</total_tax_amount>
                <allocation_code_id>29683499</allocation_code_id>
                <serial_number />
                <contract_period_type>m</contract_period_type>
                <service_period_type>m</service_period_type>
                <account_manager_when_posted>, Dominic</account_manager_when_posted>
            </invoice_item>
        </invoice>
    </account>
</invoice_batch_generic>
```

Essentially, I need to get certain data out of this XML:

- invoice_number
- total_tax_rate_per_category_and_region
- total_tax_ammount
- And then for each invoice_item I need to make an array:
- item_name
- allocation_code_external_number
- quantity
- hourly_billing_rate
- service_unit_price

Unfortunately, my XML parsing experience is nonexistent. This API feeds everything else as easy to parse objects... I'm not asking for someone to write this for me, just was hoping to get a pointer in the right direction. Here is where I make a feeble attempt to parse some of the items:

```
//THIS IS WHERE WE PULL THE XML FROM OUR API
$xmlMarkup = $AT_Client->getInvoiceMarkup($_GET['Invoice'], 'XML');
$xmlMarkupResult = $xmlMarkup->GetInvoiceMarkupResult;

//THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PARSE THINGS INTO VALUES THAT I CAN FEED INTO XERO

$dom = new DomDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");
$dom->loadXml{$xmlMarkupResult};
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$itemList = array();
$itemNodes = $xpath->query('//account/invoice/invoice_item');
for($i=0;$i<$itemNodes->length;$i++) {
    $itemList[] = $itemNodes->item($i)->nodeValue;
}

print_r($itemList);
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And `print_r($itemList);` shows __what__?

Comment: I would strongly recommend [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) if you're new to working with XML; as its name suggests, it simplifies all the common tasks like this. Make sure to read through [the usage examples in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) and not trust `print_r`, which doesn't always tell you quite the right thing when working with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using SimpleXML makes accessing the data more straightforward and (IMHO) logical.  As this is a fairly straightforward structure, you can use something like...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("t1.xml");

foreach ($xml->account->invoice as $invoice) {
    echo "Invoice id:".$invoice->invoice_id."\n";
    foreach ( $invoice->invoice_item as $item ) {
        echo "total_tax_rate_per_region_and_category:".
                (string)$item->total_tax_rate_per_region_and_category."\n";
        echo "total_tax_amount:".
                (string)$item->total_tax_amount."\n";
    }
}
```

As you can see, the load_file just reads the data in and then you can use the various levels of data as though accessing the elements of an object.  I hope that this is enough for you to start off with.

One thing I do point out is that when accessing an element, the cast to `(string)` returns the value of the element, whereas simply using the elements name is an object.

Answer (score -1):

On of the most powerful parts of the DOM extension, is its integration with XPath - in fact, DomXPath is far more powerful then the SimpleXML equivalent. This example seems quite complex, but in actuality it shows just how flexible the DOM  XPath functionality can be.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$dom->loadXml($xmlMarkupResult);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace("ns", "http://tempuri.org/invoice_batch_generic.xsd");

$rootNode = $xpath->query('/ns:invoice_batch_generic')->item(0);

// Invoice data
$invoiceNumber = $xpath->query('ns:account/ns:invoice/ns:invoice_number', $rootNode)->item(0)->nodeValue;
$taxRate = $xpath->query('ns:taxregioncategory/ns:total_tax_rate_per_category_and_region', $rootNode)->item(0)->nodeValue;
$totalTaxAmount = $xpath->query('ns:taxregioncategory/ns:total_tax_amount', $rootNode)->item(0)->nodeValue;

// Invoice items
$itemList = array();
$invoiceItemNodes = $xpath->query('ns:account/ns:invoice/ns:invoice_item', $rootNode);

/* @var $invoiceItemNode DOMNode */
foreach ($invoiceItemNodes as $invoiceItemNode) {
    $row = [];

    /* @var $field DOMNode */
    foreach ($invoiceItemNode->childNodes as $field) {
        $row[$field->tagName] = $field->nodeValue;
    }
    $itemList[] = $row;
}

print_r($itemList);
```

Comment: Outer part is good, but you can use expression to fetch the details as well: `$row = [ 'invoice_number' => $xpath->evaluate('string(invoice_id)', $invoiceItemNode), ... ]`. Additionally checking the tagName to validate that it is an element node is not elegant. Use nodeType or just validate the class (`if ($field instanceof DOMElement) { ...`).